# Columnas y Filas en Array C#

Tags: c#, array, matrices

Cuando tenemos arreglos en C# de tipo [5,6] se que el primer número son las filas  y el segundo pertenece a las columnas, es decir que tenemos 5 filas con 6 columnas cada uno. Pero en el caso de los arreglos de una dimensión pasa lo mismo? Es decir [6] algo asi estaría diciendo que tenemos 6 filas con un única columna?

Comment: O 6 columnas con una fila? cual es la diferencia.. son 6 posiciones.. y si queres verlo de otra forma, en realidad en el primer caso tenes un arrego de 5 posiciones, y cada posicion tiene un arreglo de 6. Esto es solo semantica

Comment: Lo sé, más que nada por cuestiones teóricas que practicas...

Comment: No hay teoria en esto. Se llama arreglo de 6 posiciones, o al otro se le dice matriz de 5X6, tal vez podrias aclarar mas de que duda teorica hablas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, en el caso de un array simple solo tendrias 6 items, y nada mas.

Es mas, en un `array multidimensional` tampoco existe el concepto de `filas` y `columnas`, quizas para representarlo visualmente lo hagas de esta forma pero es solo eso, una representacion, en realidad lo que tienes es una `matriz` donde en cada coordenada tienes items.

Al definir una array simple podrias definir un tipo custom con una clase, como ser

```
public class Item{
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public string prop2 {get;set;}
    public string prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

al definir

```
Item[] items = new Item[6];
items[0] = new Item() { prop1 = "val1", prop2 = "val2", prop3 = "val3" };
```

en este caso tambien defines `items` que podria verse como `rows` y las `propiedades` de la `clase` podrian representar las `columnas`

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo, en si más que nada lo preguntaba por cuando se representa gráficamente, ya en práctica es diferentes pues cada elemento cuenta en su interior con otros más. Muchas gracias

Comment: claro, despues depende que tipo de dato definas para el item, si es un valor simple como string, int, etc o uno complejo con una clase